# How to Map Data in embedded systems?

Tags: c, dictionary, mapping, stm32

I am asking the question for the second time because the first time I apparently did not manage to get my request across (insert a sad smiley here).The previous post has been deleted as I thought it could just add to the confusion if I just edit it.

**Problem**: I am getting a packet of data (payload) from a data source. This data is given to me in an array and I would like to split this data (like in a gateway) and send it to other peripherals.

The package data I received could look like this:

```
uint8_t received_payload[] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66};
```

It is noticeable that what is behind this data is not apparent. This is because it can be measurement data, which can sometimes come from several sensors and these measurement values ​​were thrown together in a data package.

I can assume that the measured values ​​come periodically and that I can recognize data packets based on an ID. (This does not matter here, however).
What is interesting for me now is that I want to pass on these measured values. Under certain circumstances split into two or more separate messages.

The order and position should be given somehow and somewhere.

In the following I have shown an example of how these can be listed. I would like to emphasize again that this is only an EXAMPLE and that I have freely come up with these values. I just want to show visually how the data could be swapped under certain circumstances.

```
uint8_t totransmit_payload_1[] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33};
uint8_t totransmit_payload_2[] = {0x44, 0x66, 0x55};
```

So I would like to have something stored somewhere that corresponds to the following information content:

```
totransmit_payload_1[0] = received_payload[0];
totransmit_payload_1[1] = received_payload[1];
totransmit_payload_1[2] = received_payload[2];
totransmit_payload_2[0] = received_payload[3];
totransmit_payload_2[1] = received_payload[5];
totransmit_payload_2[2] = received_payload[4];
```

This process should work bidirectionally and have a kind of dynamic because it won't be possible for me to write "how the data is split up" in the code.(Before questions arise. When I boot my system via SPI, I get a configuration file from a MicroSD card which describes how my system should behave.)

Of course I have already tried to find solutions on the World Wide Web, but I find it difficult to find something for my low level application. I am on a microcontroller of the STM class and only program in C.
What I found that would fit my application would be a kind of mapping.
Here as references: [What Is Data Mapping?](https://wult.io/blog/data-mapping-examples-how-to-field-database-merge-map/)

Do you guys or girls have experience with something like that? Or ideas on how something like this could work efficiently?

Thanks for your help :D

Edit: I just want to know the best way to save in C which position in an array references to another position in another array.
Without hardcoding it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you you start asking about data copying, then change midway to data mapping?  Anyway, these are small examples of both:

```
#include <string.h>  // for memcpy
...
void CopyBytes(const* uint8_t received_payload, uint8_t* totransmit_payload_1, uint8_t* totransmit_payload_2)
{
  // of course you'll need to make sure these buffers are appropriately sized
  memcpy(totransmit_payload_1, received_payload, 3);
  memcpy(totransmit_payload_2, received_payload + 3, 3);
}
```

Learn more about [`memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) on the man page.

If you want some data mapping instead, I would create space for the actual data in one place (the receive buffer for instance), then you can have as many pointers as you want pointing to that data:

```
uint8_t received_payload[] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66};

uint8_t* totransmit_payload_1[3];  // creates an array of uint8_t _pointers_
uint8_t* totransmit_payload_2[3];  // does the same

// now you can do your mapping
totransmit_payload_1[0] = &(received_payload[0]);  // save the _address_ of received_payload[0] to totransmit_payload_1[0]
totransmit_payload_1[1] = &(received_payload[1]);  // (don't think the parentheses are necessary, but I like them to be perfectly clear the [] dereference happens first)
totransmit_payload_1[2] = &(received_payload[2]);
totransmit_payload_2[0] = &(received_payload[3]);
totransmit_payload_2[1] = &(received_payload[5]);
totransmit_payload_2[2] = &(received_payload[4]);
```

Now, any time data changes in `received_payload`, you can access it from the `totransmit_payload` structures since they point to that data.  For example:

```
received_payload[0] = 5;
printf("received_payload[0] = %" PRIu8 "\n", *(totransmit_payload_1[0]));  // prints 5;

// It's "bi-directional", you can dereference the pointer and assign a value to that memory location, then access it from received_payload
*(totransmit_payload_2[2]) = 17;
printf("received_payload[4] = %" PRIu8 "\n", received_payload[4]); // prints 17
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the Answer. I tried to discribe how I should store information about "where data has to be copied to". So your answer is intresting, but sadly not answering my Question :C

Comment: @Yoschhi_97 then I am bumfuzzled what you're asking about, hopefully somebody else can figure it out.

Comment: maybe the edit helps to describe my problem ^^'?

Comment: @Yoschhi_97 not particularly. In fact I still think that's what I answered. You say without hardcoding it .. then you need to think of some algorithm/pattern that does the mapping. The first three mappings are easy enough, x --> x. But the next 3 are 0 --> 3, 1 --> 5, and 2 -->4 .. ? You tell me, how did you come up with that mapping? Realistically, for only 6 items there's nothing wrong with hardcoding it IMO; that will be faster than a loop or something. But if this is a small example and you have hundreds or thousands of mappings to create, then yeah you'll need to think of a better way.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and effort. I think I found something. It's some work with Hashtables and linked list. But to possibly describe my problem again (I can't accept that I'm too stupid to explain it) I have a microcontroller and a configuration file on which is in XML format writen which data packet i have to accept, where data of intrest is stored in this packet and how and where these have to be send out. So the User himself can decide the behavior of my Gateway, by changing the XML file.

Comment: @Yoschhi_97 Hah, you're not too stupid to explain it. Two way street, I need understand it! Ok so you want the mapping defined in the xml file? Good deal, yeah that could get trickier. Hash table sounds like a good approach, mapping is what they do. If you still need some help, it will be best to ask a new question, and probably want to mention the mapping should be defined in an xml file. Good luck!